# remove groups with different count within a group - data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

i want to check that the `count` variable has the same value across all `years` within an `ID` group. if it is not, i want to remove the whole `ID` group from the data:

```
ID <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3), rep("D", 3))
year <- c(rep(c(2012,2013,2014), 4))
count <- c(rep(7, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(2, 3), c(1,1,2))
testDT <- as.data.table(cbind(ID, count, year))
```

desired output:

```
ID <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3))
year <- c(rep(c(2012,2013,2014), 3))
count <- c(rep(7, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(2, 3))
testDT <- as.data.table(cbind(ID, count, year))
```

Comment: `ID` `B` has `count` 4 and 2 i.e not similar across all years.  Why is it still in final output?

Comment: made a mistake while copy-paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the unique values of `count` and select only the groups which have 1 unique values.

```
library(data.table)
testDT[, .SD[uniqueN(count) == 1], ID]

#   ID count year
#1:  A     7 2012
#2:  A     7 2013
#3:  A     7 2014
#4:  B     4 2012
#5:  B     4 2013
#6:  B     4 2014
#7:  C     2 2012
#8:  C     2 2013
#9:  C     2 2014
```

Another option is to test for `var` and `sd`, if the `count` is same for the entire group, variance and standard deviation would be 0.

```
testDT[, .SD[var(count) == 0], ID]
testDT[, .SD[sd(count) == 0], ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a typo in the question and the second 'B' should have been 'C':

You can test that the max and min are the same for each ID:

```
testDT[, isOK:=(min(count)==max(count)), by='ID']
```

Then filter out bad IDs as needed:

```
testDT[isOK==TRUE]
```